# How to extract outer div contents without parsing inner div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a div such as:

```
    <div class="info">
                 Illinois
                    <div class="price">
                        $20
                    </div>
    </div>
```

I want to get the contents of the "info" div, but without the contents of the "price" div. I am using Python and BeutifulSoup. I was trying to turn the div contents into a string which I can easily filter, but my code doesn't work:

```
infosoup = soup.find_all('div', class_="info")
for element in infosoup:
    name = element.string.strip()
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contents` list:

```
infosoup = soup.find_all('div', class_="info")
for element in infosoup:
    name = element.contents[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use the `text=True` parameter of the `find` command rather than try to index the list of contents.

```
matches = [div.find(text=True).strip() for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="info")]
```

Returns:

```
['Illinois']
```